# How to delete items from array in .txt C

Tags: c

I have this function to add clients on a .txt but now i wanna delete one who you puts.
I want to go through the array to find the client entered in the "removeClient" function
[The full code is here:
https://pastebin.com/xaJ61THK](https://pastebin.com/xaJ61THK)

The function to add clientes is:

```
void aniadirCliente()
{

    if(clientes[n].dni[0]=='\0'){
        printf("\nIntroduce el nombre del archivo: \nNombre por defecto: clientes.txt\n\n");
        gets(nom_archivo);
        fflush(stdin);
        //Cuando abrimos el fichero le tenemos que poner rw para que podamos escribir y leer.
        archivo=fopen(nom_archivo,"rw");
        if ((archivo = fopen(nom_archivo, "rw")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\n\nEl archivo no existe.");
            system("cls"); //En windows limpia pantalla
        }else
        {
            int i;
            printf("\n\nArchivo cargado correctamente.|\n");
            for(i=0; i<max_clientes;i++){
                fscanf(archivo,"\n %s %s %s %s",clientes[i].dni,clientes[i].nombre,clientes[i].apellidos,clientes[i].direccion);
            }
            for(i=0;i<max_clientes;i++)
            {
                if(clientes[i].dni[0]=='\0')
                {
                    //Crear un nuevo cliente, lo mismo que antes los espacios con _
                    puts("DNI:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].dni);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", clientes[i].dni);

                    puts("Nombre:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].nombre);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", &clientes[i].nombre);

                    puts("Apellidos:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].apellidos);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", &clientes[i].apellidos);

                    puts("Direccion:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].direccion);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", &clientes[i].direccion);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

}
            fclose(archivo);
            system("cls");

}
```

Function to delete clients. ¿How i can delete all of this client?:clientes[i].dni, clientes[i].nombre, clientes[i].apellido, clientes[i].direccion.

```
void eliminarCliente(){

 if(clientes[n].dni[0]=='\0')
        {
            printf("\nIntroduce el nombre del archivo: \nNombre por defecto: clientes.txt\n\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(nom_archivo);
            //Cuando abrimos el fichero le tenemos que poner rw para que podamos escribir y leer.
            archivo=fopen(nom_archivo,"rw");
            if ((archivo = fopen(nom_archivo, "rw")) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "\n\nEl archivo no existe.");
            }else{
                int i, y;
                char delcliente;
                for(i=0; i<max_clientes;i++){
            fscanf(archivo,"\n %s %s %s %s",clientes[i].dni,clientes[i].nombre,clientes[i].apellidos,clientes[i].direccion);
        }
                printf("Introduce el dni del cliente que deseas eliminar");
                scanf("%s", &delcliente);
                if(delcliente==clientes[i].dni){

                    printf("Cliente Eliminado");
                    //How to delete all of the client
                }
                else{
                    printf("El dni introducido no coincide");
                }

                }
        }


}
```

Comment: Unless you allocate the memory dynamically, you can't really "delete" elements from an array. Arrays have a fixed size, and will keep that size during their whole life-time. You can keep the current top-index in a variable, when "deleting" an element, move the elements above in index down a step, and update the top-index. Or if holes are okay, then set an element to a value that indicates "empty".

Comment: You'd think there was a duplicate for this, but I can't find one really similar enough.

Comment: Well, the basic recipe for deleting element `m` of an array `arr` containing `n` elements is `for(int i = m; i < n-1; i++) arr[i] = arr[i+1]; n--;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want delete an element of an array using static memory, you need three things:

- First: You must know name of your array. In this example, array will be stored in var `array`
- Second: You must know index of the element you wanna delete, in the example will stored in var `indexToDelete`
- Third: Length of the array, in the example will stored in var `arrayLength`

Once known this, you need implement next loop:

```
for (i = indexToDelete; i < arrayLength - 1; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i+1];
}
```

This loop will go over element to element since the index you wanna delete (`i = indexToDelete`) up to the total lenght of the array minus one (`i < arrayLenght - 1`). This minus one is because of you are copying in element `i` the element `i+i` so maximum lenght of the loop must be `arrayLenght - 1` as we set up.

Currently, `array[arrayLength] = array[arrayLength-1]` due to the previously implemented loop. So, finally, we need to delete last item (`array[arrayLength]`). To do that:

```
clientes[arrayLength].dni[0] = '\0';
clientes[arrayLength].nombre[0] = '\0';
clientes[arrayLength].apellidos[0] = '\0';
clientes[arrayLength].direccion[0] = '\0';
```

Once done all that, you will have removed your item successfuly.

---

**EXTRA:**

Extrapolating all this to your code would be something such that:

```
// You need correct this things: 

// delcliente is an array of chars, not a only char
char delcliente[9+1]; // DNI has 8 numbers, 1 letter, and '\0' character = Length 10

printf("Introduce el dni del cliente que deseas eliminar");
gets(delcliente); // User input a DNI to remove

// Go over all clientes
for (i = 0; i < max_clientes; i++) {
    // To compare string we use strcmp() 
    if(strcmp(delcliente, clientes[i].dni) == 0) {

        //How to delete all of the client
        for (j = i; j < max_clientes - 1; j++) {
            array[j] = array[j+1];
        }

        clientes[max_clientes].dni[0] = '\0';
        clientes[max_clientes].nombre[0] = '\0';
        clientes[max_clientes].apellidos[0] = '\0';
        clientes[max_clientes].direccion[0] = '\0';

        // Show success message
        printf("Cliente Eliminado");
    }                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To "delete" an element from a stack-allocated array is really just to overwrite it and shift future elements back by one. To do this, you will need `memmove`

```
/* delelem: Removes element at zero-based index at from array array of 
   size size */
void delelem(int *array, size_t size, int at)
{
    if (at < size-1)
        memmove(&array[at], &array[at+1], 
                ((size - 1) - at) * sizeof(array[0]));
    array[size - 1] = 0; /* use 0 to denote an empty element. In order for
                            this to work, use memset to zero out the array 
                            when it is first created */
}
```

Rewriting this code to use client objects is trivial.